# Calculate source value from deviation of Bollinger Bands with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the standard deviation of the rolling mean (Bollinger Bands, example here is very simplified) in a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

no_of_std = 3
window = 20

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [34, 34, 34, 33, 32, 34, 35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31]})

rolling_mean = df['A'].rolling(window).mean()
rolling_std = df['A'].rolling(window).std(ddof=0)

df['M'] = rolling_mean
df['BBL'] = rolling_mean - (rolling_std * no_of_std)
df['BBH'] = rolling_mean + (rolling_std * no_of_std)

print (df)
```

The result looks like this:

```
       A      M        BBL        BBH
0   34.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
1   34.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
2   34.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
3   33.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
4   32.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
5   34.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
6   35.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
7   21.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
8   22.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
9   25.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
10  23.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
11  21.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
12  39.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
13  26.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
14  31.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
15  34.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
16  38.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
17  26.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
18  21.0    NaN        NaN        NaN
19  39.0  30.10  11.633544  48.566456
20  31.0  29.95  11.665375  48.234625
```

Now i want to calculate in the other direction which value the last value in the column 'A' needs to have to hit exactly the 3rd standard deviation of the rolling mean.
That means in other words i want to calculate: which value needs A to have in a next row nr.15 that it will be exactly the same as the value in BBH or BBL.
I can do this by recursive approximation but this needs a lot of perfomance and i think there must be a better way. Here is an example for the solution from which i think it is to slow and there must be a better faster way:

```
import pandas as pd


odf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [34, 34, 34, 33, 32, 34, 35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31]})

def get_last_bbh_bbl(idf):
    xdf = idf.copy()
    no_of_std = 3
    window = 20
    rolling_mean = xdf['A'].rolling(window).mean()
    rolling_std = xdf['A'].rolling(window).std()
    xdf['M'] = rolling_mean
    xdf['BBL'] = rolling_mean - (rolling_std * no_of_std)
    xdf['BBH'] = rolling_mean + (rolling_std * no_of_std)
    bbh = xdf.loc[len(xdf) - 1, 'BBH']
    bbl = xdf.loc[len(xdf) - 1, 'BBL']
    return bbh, bbl

def search_matching_value(idf, low, high, search_for):
    xdf = idf.copy()
    if abs(high-low) < 0.000001:
        return high

    middle = low + ((high-low)/2)
    xdf = xdf.append({'A' : middle}, ignore_index=True)
    bbh, bbl = get_last_bbh_bbl(xdf)
    if search_for == 'bbh':
        if bbh < middle:
            result=search_matching_value(idf, low, middle, search_for)
        elif bbh > middle:
            result=search_matching_value(idf, middle, high, search_for)
        else:
            return middle
    elif search_for == 'bbl':
        if bbl > middle:
            result=search_matching_value(idf, middle, high, search_for)
        elif bbl < middle:
            result=search_matching_value(idf, low, middle, search_for)
        else:
            return middle
    return result

actual_bbh, actual_bbl = get_last_bbh_bbl(odf)
last_value = odf.loc[len(odf) - 1, 'A']
print('last_value: {}, actual bbh: {}, actual bbl: {}'.format(last_value, actual_bbh, actual_bbl))
low = last_value
high = actual_bbh * 10
next_value_that_hits_bbh = search_matching_value(odf, low, high, 'bbh')
print ('next_value_that_hits_bbh: {}'.format(next_value_that_hits_bbh))
low=0
high=last_value
next_value_that_hits_bbl = search_matching_value(odf, low, high, 'bbl')
print ('next_value_that_hits_bbl: {}'.format(next_value_that_hits_bbl))
```

the result looks like this:

```
 last_value: 31.0, actual bbh: 48.709629106422284, actual bbl: 11.190370893577711
 next_value_that_hits_bbh: 57.298733206475276
 next_value_that_hits_bbl: 2.174952656030655
```

Comment: you would find the next value in A with  the same last values in M , BBL and BBH ?

Comment: No i want to know the next Value of A which is identical with BBl or BBH. I A is higher i get a higher BBH and so on. At the moment i do this with a recursion.

Comment: ok for recursion, but by using dichotomy is fast?

Comment: i changed the example, the window was to small with ten units and added an example for the recursion

Comment: i have fixed my errors , the new solution seems ok... i have the same results than yours!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here one solution to calculate next value with fast algorithm: newton opt and newton classic are faster than dichotomy and this solution dont use dataframe to recalculate the different value, i use directly the statistic function from the library of same name

some info for [scipy.optimize.newton](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html)

```
from scipy import misc
import pandas as pd
import statistics
from scipy.optimize import newton
#scipy.optimize if you want to test the newton optimized function

def get_last_bbh_bbl(idf):
    xdf = idf.copy()
    rolling_mean = xdf['A'].rolling(window).mean()
    rolling_std = xdf['A'].rolling(window).std()
    xdf['M'] = rolling_mean
    xdf['BBL'] = rolling_mean - (rolling_std * no_of_std)
    xdf['BBH'] = rolling_mean + (rolling_std * no_of_std)
    bbh = xdf.loc[len(xdf) - 1, 'BBH']
    bbl = xdf.loc[len(xdf) - 1, 'BBL']
    lastvalue = xdf.loc[len(xdf) - 1, 'A']
    return lastvalue, bbh, bbl

#classic newton
def NewtonsMethod(f, x, tolerance=0.00000001):
    while True:
        x1 = x - f(x) / misc.derivative(f, x)
        t = abs(x1 - x)
        if t < tolerance:
            break
        x = x1
    return x

#to calculate the result of function bbl(x) - x (we want 0!)
def low(x):
    l = lastlistofvalue[:-1]
    l.append(x)
    avg = statistics.mean(l)
    std = statistics.stdev(l, avg)
    return avg - std * no_of_std - x

#to calculate the result of function bbh(x) - x (we want 0!)
def high(x):
    l = lastlistofvalue[:-1]
    l.append(x)
    avg = statistics.mean(l)
    std = statistics.stdev(l, avg)
    return avg + std * no_of_std - x

odf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [34, 34, 34, 33, 32, 34, 35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31]})
no_of_std = 3
window = 20
lastlistofvalue = odf['A'].shift(0).to_list()[::-1][:window]

"""" Newton classic method """
x = odf.loc[len(odf) - 1, 'A']
x0 = NewtonsMethod(high, x)
print(f'value to hit bbh: {x0}')
odf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [34, 34, 34, 33, 32, 34, 35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31, x0]})
lastvalue, new_bbh, new_bbl = get_last_bbh_bbl(odf)
print(f'value to hit bbh: {lastvalue} -> check new bbh: {new_bbh}')

x0 = NewtonsMethod(low, x)
print(f'value to hit bbl: {x0}')
odf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [34, 34, 34, 33, 32, 34, 35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31, x0]})
lastvalue, new_bbh, new_bbl = get_last_bbh_bbl(odf)
print(f'value to hit bbl: {lastvalue} -> check new bbl: {new_bbl}')
```

output:

```
value to hit bbh: 57.298732375228624
value to hit bbh: 57.298732375228624 -> check new bbh: 57.29873237527272
value to hit bbl: 2.1749518354059636
value to hit bbl: 2.1749518354059636 -> check new bbl: 2.1749518353102992
```

you could compare the newton optimized like:

```
""" Newton optimized method """
x = odf.loc[len(odf) - 1, 'A']
x0 = newton(high, x, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.00e-08, maxiter=50, fprime2=None)
print(f'Newton opt value to hit bbh: {x0}')

x0 = newton(low, x, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=50, fprime2=None)
print(f'Newton value to hit bbl: {x0}')
```

output:

```
Newton opt value to hit bbh: 57.29873237532118
Newton value to hit bbl: 2.1749518352051225
```

with the newton optimized, you could play with the max iteration

and optimized is faster than classic:

measures for each calculus

**0.002 sec  for optimized**

**0.005 sec  for classic**

***Remarks: ***

if you use rolling(window).std() you are using the standard deviation so you have to use

`std = statistics.stdev(l, avg)`    you divide by N-1 items

if you use rolling(window).std(`ddof=0`) you are using the population deviation so you have to use

`std = statistics.pstdev(l, avg)`   you divide by N items

Comment: I want to know which Value of A would be identical with BBL and which value of A would be identical with BBH.

Comment: The values cannot be correct. The upper Bollingerband (BBH) in line 14 is 50.37. So the result for bbh must be something much nearer to this value than 37.66. If i add the result of 37.66 to the dataframe (  df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [35.0, 21, 22, 25, 23, 21, 39, 26, 31, 34, 38, 26, 21, 39, 31, 37.66]})  ) i get 50.37 for the last BBH.

Comment: i changed the example, the window was to small with ten units and added an example for the recursion

Comment: i have fixed my error to test value action = bbh or value = bbl  ... and not bbh or bbl = last value of bbh or bbl

Comment: you  could decrease the tolerance, you have just needed 3 numbers after the dot.

Comment: newton optimized is 30times faster than my recursion !